# Symfony 4 does not find translation files after deploy

Tags: php, symfony, internationalization, translation, symfony4

We have configured Symfony 4.4 to use translations and everything seems to be working fine locally. I can change language, the translation files are found and the whole thing works like a charm. But after deploying all the strings **are the keys to the translations and NOT the custom translations that we added to the system.**
We use docker and k8s to deploy so everything is running on the same version and the same container that we have locally.

Also here is the config for the translations:
Translations.yaml

```
parameters:
    locale: 'sv'
    app_locales: 'sv|en'
framework:
    default_locale: 'sv'
    translator:
        default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/translations'
        fallbacks:
            - 'sv'
```

And here is the event subscriber:

```
<?php
namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

class LocaleSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $defaultLocale;

    public function __construct(string $defaultLocale = 'sv')
    {
        $this->defaultLocale = $defaultLocale;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $request->setLocale($request->getSession()->get('_locale', $this->defaultLocale));
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            // must be registered before (i.e. with a higher priority than) the default Locale listener
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => [['onKernelRequest', 101]],
        ];
    }
}
```

What happens is that there is a flag on the header that acts like a toggle, firing up a method that changes the session value for locale and then this event subscriber picks that from the session before the request and loads the translations.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused because there was no command in the dockerfile to copy the translations directory (where translations are located) to the container.
Adding this command to the **Dockerfile** did the trick:

```
COPY /translations /symfony/translations
```